# How do we intertwine google collaboratory to WordPress?

Tags: python-3.x, wordpress

We have created a Website with WordPress, here the issue is that I want to run python codes.
For example, I want to make a linear regression and show the procedure with the Python language as well as download necessary libraries for my codes.
I have seen that there are plug-ins that can help but they are not fully developed.
How can i install python in wordPress?